# How to convert this command from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
// Traditional approach,
// fluent interface
BsonArray a2 = new BsonArray().Add(1).Add(2);

// Values argument
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2 };
BsonArray a3 = new BsonArray(values); //It doesn't work in VB.NET

// Collection initializer syntax
BsonArray a4 = new BsonArray { 1, 2 }; //This doesn't work in VB.NET
```

In particular, I want to find "within" box in [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) VB.NET driver.

How do I collapse the following statements into one line?

```
Dim b As New BsonDocument
Dim box As New BsonDocument
Dim d = New BsonArray({{1, 2}, {3, 5}})
box.Add("$box", d)
'box.Add("$box", d)
b.Add("$within", box)
query.Add("$within", box)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say the second and third ones don't work?  It appears that the BsonArray constructor has an overload that takes an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)`, so both of those should work (except your syntax is wrong, that is.  The correct syntax would be:

```
' values argument
Dim values() As Integer = {1, 2}
Dim a3 As BsonArray = New BsonArray(values)

' collection initializer syntax
Dim a4 As BsonArray = New BsonArray(New Integer(){1, 2})
```